# Add SVN to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, svn

I am wondering if there is any tool, or puling to control a database in SQL Server 2008.

I've already tried Agent SVN and SQL Source Control 3.0 of RedGate but both of them are [1]>free or< too expensive for my pocket.

I also tried http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15962/SQL-Server-database-versioning-with-Subversion-SVN but it's out of date....

Any suggestion? What should I try?

What I want is a source control in the changes done inside the DB, not in the files that generate it.

Edit: [1] both of them are too expensive, not free

Comment: [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) also uses SQL Server for its storage - and it's free for single developers.

Comment: What do you mean by "both of them are free or too expensive"? So are they free or expensive? :)

Comment: @bahrep both of them are expensive, not free. Sorry for the mistake.